# Django: passing variable from view.py to html with render

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I have the following problem

With views.py I render a page called 'results_links.html' located in application templates directory which has an 'include' statement toward another page 'MAPE_history.csv.html' located in 'upload' directory (which is also defined in settings.py as template directory). I want to dynamically pass the file to be used in 'included' statement from views.py. For the test I use same file: MAPE_history.csv.html 
The problem I have is that I receive a 'template not existing'error from include statement. If I remove the statement of I replace the 'content' variable with the file name, I do not receive a problem.
Here is the code:

```
    ### views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
from formupload import Best_model_forecast_v11

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'what':'Django File Upload'})

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        MAPE_file = 'MAPE_'+str(request.FILES['file'])+'.html'
        return render(request,'result_links.html',{'content':MAPE_file})
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request,'result_links.html',{'content':'MAPE_history.csv.html'})
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'upload/MAPE_history.csv; filename="MAPE_history.csv"'
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Failed")

def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):

    if not os.path.exists('upload/'):
        os.mkdir('upload/')
    if not os.path.exists('forecast/'):
        os.mkdir('forecast/')
    with open('upload/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    #print(Best_model_forecast_v11.main('upload/' + filename))
    return Best_model_forecast_v11.main('upload/' + filename)

### result_links.html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rezultate</title>
<IMG SRC="logo.jpg" ALT="" WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=100>
</head>
<a href="D:/FLORIAN/Django/mysite/upload/MAPE_history.csv.html">forecast</a>

{% block content %}
    {% include 'logo.html' %}
    {% include '{content}' %} # 'template not existing' error is coming from this statement!


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="{content}"/>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Rezultate" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ content.relative_path }}'>{{content}}</a>
{% endblock %}

</html>

### settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates','d:/florian/django/mysite/upload/'),
            'd:/florian/django/mysite/upload/'
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
### error
TemplateDoesNotExist at /upload/
{content}
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/upload/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
{content}
Exception Location: C:\Users\lored\Envs\simpleform\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py in find_template, line 148
Python Executable:  C:\Users\lored\Envs\simpleform\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.0
Python Path:    
['D:\\FLORIAN\\Django\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform\\Scripts\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python35\\Lib',
 'c:\\python35\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform',
 'C:\\Users\\lored\\Envs\\simpleform\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 28 Nov 2017 18:27:27 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: d:\florian\django\mysite\upload\{content} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: d:\florian\django\mysite\upload\{content} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\lored\Envs\simpleform\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\{content} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\lored\Envs\simpleform\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\{content} (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\FLORIAN\Django\mysite\formupload\templates\{content} (Source does not exist)
```

templates directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se9oX.jpg)

Comment: is this not covered in the django project tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

The template name can either be a variable or a hard-coded (quoted) string, in either single or double quotes.
Try using `{% include content %}`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing variables in Django like this requires double braces; change your {content} line to {{ content }}.

As an aside, check your "elif request.method == 'GET':" code, as the second return will never be reached.

Comment: I tried with all variants, double braces included. What is very strange: in the link statement {{content}} is working but not in the included statement... <a href="{{content}}">forecast</a>      TemplateDoesNotExist at /upload/
{{content}}
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/upload/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
{{content}}

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using if elif try this one

```html
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        MAPE_file = 'MAPE_'+str(request.FILES['file'])+'.html'
        return render(request,'result_links.html',{'content':MAPE_file})
  
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'upload/MAPE_history.csv; filename="MAPE_history.csv"'
    return render(request,'result_links.html',{'content':'MAPE_history.csv.html'})
```

Comment: I am using elif because I do two different things: 1) when I upload the file, I run a custom py (best_model....) and I generate the 'MAPE_MAPE_history.csv.html' file which is save also in 'upload' directory. My goal now is 2) to be able to download the newly generated MAPE_history.csv.html file and I try to do this through the 'result_links.html' page where I use 'GET' method which is pointing back into 'elif'. If I can achieve my goal to simply download the resulted file, than I am willing to use any other suitable method. Thanks.